# props failes to render with defineProps<SomePropType>()

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I've some components, with one parent element from which I tried to pass the props using `defineProps<{}>()` syntax. The setup is basic, on root level I've one **types.ts** file, one parent vue file (*viz.* **CardItem**), and the components.

What I've done so far...

```js
/* types.ts */
export type IItem = { title: string; description: string };

/* DetailedCard.vue */
<script setup lang="ts">
import TestItem from "../test.vue";
</script>

<TestItem :title="'hello world'" :description="'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'" />

/* TestItem.vue */
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { IItem } from "@/types";
const { title, description } = defineProps<IItem>();
</script>

<template>{{ title }} {{ description }}</template>
```

error(s) I'm getting:

> [@vue/compiler-sfc] type argument passed to `defineProps()` must be a literal type, or a reference to an interface or literal type.

And, if I want it to use like this way...

```js
... ...

interface Item extends IItem {}
const { title, description } = defineProps<Item>();
```

then I'm getting warnings on runtime:

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Property "title" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
> at `<Test title="hello" description="world" >`
> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Property "description" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.
> at `<Test title="hello" description="world" >`

The only way it works, if I directly define an interface/type on this *TestItem* component.

```js
interface Item { title: string; description: string; };
const { title, description } = defineProps<Item>();
```

So, what's going wrong!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *expected behavior*. Referring to the "TypeScript with Composition API" page in the documentation, we get to [this section](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#syntax-limitations), which states:

> In order to generate the correct runtime code, the generic argument for defineProps() must be one of the following:
>
> - An object literal type:
>
> ```
> defineProps<{ /*... */ }>()
> ```
>
> - A reference to an interface or object literal type in **the same file**:
>
> ```
> interface Props {/* ... */}
>
> defineProps<Props>()
> ```

Just below that, it also mentions that you cannot import the type from another file:

> The interface or object literal type can contain references to types imported from other files, however, the generic argument itself passed to `defineProps` **cannot be an imported type**.

So the only way you can define your props, is as you noted:

```
interface Item { title: string; description: string; };

const { title, description } = defineProps<Item>();
```

or inlining the interface:

```
const { title, description } = defineProps<{ title: string; description: string; }>();
```

Comment: Okay! thanks.... So, in a typical e-comm app we've to define types per module level, as importing & extending doesn't help. 

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not entirely true anymore for Vue 3.3 upwards. From the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#syntax-limitations):

> This limitation has been resolved in 3.3. The latest version of Vue supports referencing imported and a limited set of complex types in the type parameter position. However, because the type to runtime conversion is still AST-based, some complex types that require actual type analysis, e.g. conditional types, are not supported. You can use conditional types for the type of a single prop, but not the entire props object.

Note the limitation about complex types though, sometimes you still need to declare types in the SFC file, f.e. with generic components like this:

```
// Example.vue
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
import type SomeComplexTypeWithGeneric from "somewhere";

defineProps<SomeTypeWithGeneric<T>>() // May lead to runtime errors

</script>

// somewhere.ts
...
type SomeComplexTypeWithGeneric<T> = Pick<SomeOtherType<T>, "someProp"> & {
  anotherProp: any
}
...
```

If you define `SomeComplexTypeWithGeneric` inside `Example.vue` everything works fine.